# How do i install Monodevelop IDE on windows 10

Tags: installation, mono, windows-10, monodevelop

I didnt get any direct link to install Monodevelop IDE. I have downloaded the items in the following link "https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/". But i got only a command ui for compiling the programs written in a notepad or an editor.is it possible to have GUI for monodevelop . Is it require VS2017 for having a Monodevelop IDE.

Comment: https://github.com/lextm/monodevelop-windows/releases

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Installation Guide](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/windows/) (https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/windows/),  the command prompt is correct.

> The installer creates a “Open Mono Command Prompt” shortcut under the
>   Mono program group in the start menu. This shortcut starts a command
>   shell with Mono-relevant path information already configured, which
>   means all the Mono tools “just work”.

If you want the MonoDevelop IDE, you should download it from the [MonoDevelop IDE](http://www.monodevelop.com/) website as described in the MonoDevelop IDE section of the link you provided.